# Is there a statement which can not be proved in any axiom systems

Tags: axioms, proof-theory, incompleteness

As we know a statement may not be proved in some axiom system according to the godel incompleteness theory, can we always solve it  by some way that change the axiom system?

Comment: $\exists x(x\neq x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply include that statement as an axiom.

Comment: can i think the infinite axiom system by continually adding the statement as a new axiom can be no problems that are undermined?

Comment: @Lufamily: It is indeed possible to have a *complete* theory -- however, if you are able to discuss the natural numbers within it, it's guaranteed that there does not exist any algorithm for identifying precisely which axioms you've included. Part of the problem is that there cannot be a general algorithm for deciding whether a particular statement can be proven or disproven from a computable set of axioms.

Comment: If it is required that the system be consistent, what if the statement is $\exists x\;(x\ne x)$ as sugggested in the comment by  Asaf Karagila?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: If one intends to modify to the original question to require consistency, one should also modify the original question to ask about a statement that can be neither proven nor disproven.